# AngularJS SPA within Umbraco

Tags: angularjs, iis, routes, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 6.4 website, under which I am now trying to put an AngularJS 2 SPA.

Umbraco: `/`

Angular: `/appname`

My problem is with the routing that is done by Umbraco. Since Umbraco handles all of the routing up to the root level, when the Angular app gets refreshed: `/appname/apage` I get a `404 - Not Found`.

I have added a URL rewrite in the `UrlRewriting.config`, however I have done it in a way that the destination url is always the `index.html` file.

```
<add name="myapp" virtualUrl="^~/myapp/*" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/myapp/index.html" ignoreCase="true" />
```

What I would like to be able to do is define a rewrite which lets me override the Umbraco routing whenever the path begins with `/myapp/`.

I have read [this](http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/angular-powered-frontend/) blog post, but it doesn't really relate to my problem because the way I have built my SPA, it doesn't have anything to do with Umbraco. Also, I must have Umbraco as the root directory, and therefore I cannot rely on IIS to do this for me either.

It would be great if someone, anyone, could point me in the direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who may have a similar issue:

I able to work around this problem by adding a `web.config` to the `/appname` directory and added the following configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="ruleName" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="/myapp/" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```